# Got error using LWP

Tags: perl, lwp

I was trying to use LWP in perl, and I followed the example given in the link:http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html,

But I got errors as such:

"www.google.com" is not exported by the LWP::Simple module

Can't continue after import errors at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/LWP/Simple.pm line 23

And here is my code:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl -w
     use LWP::Simple

    $url = 'www.google.com';
    $content = get $url;
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You did see the date on the example, yes?

Comment: Well, first of all try to put the semicolon symbol after your `use LWP::Simple` statement

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: @vonbrand, actually the code at the link is reasonably well-formed perl, declaring both variables as lexicals.

Comment: you forgot `;` after `use LWP::Simple`

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma : And you forgot to read _ArtM's_ comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a semicolon after your `use` statement, and your URL needs to have a protocol specified.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use LWP::Simple;

 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $url = 'http://www.google.com';
 my $content = get $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You missed the semicolon after `use LWP::Simple`.

Answer (score 0):

Had you used `strict` it would have told you that you have to declare `$url`. But if you declared both variables, you would still have gotten the error you did.

So, it's not a simple case of USUW.

Because you didn't put a semi-colon after the import statement, perl is assigning the string `'www.google.com'` to the autovariable `$url`. And then, as it is an expression that can be passed, it passes that value as an export arguments of `LWP::Simple`.

Modules expect that any values passed as arguments to its import process, are symbols that the module--or Exporter--knows how to export.

So it's telling you that the whatever that string that you passed in is, it's not something that the module exports.

So, you just have to get used to this type of message pointing out that something is wrong with your import statement.